# how to write regular expression to match the repeated strings and designate the repeated number?

Tags: regex

for example, i want to match the string "abcabc" in a text file, where the two (and only two) "abc"  are attached together, and no characters are in front of and at the end of "abcabc"?

if i use grep -n '(abc){2}' TEST, it does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape the parentesis:

```
grep -n '\(abc\)\{2\}' TEST
```

if you want to match the string `abcabc` alone on a line, as your description seems to suggest, use:

```
grep -n '^\(abc\)\{2\}$' TEST
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the shortest alternative:

```
^abcabc$
```

Comment: This only matches if this is the only string on the line, it depends a bit on what is meant by 'no characters are in front of and at the end of "abcabc"'

Comment: Bram, agreed! IMO, if Allen wants to match "the string 'abcabc' ... and no characters are in front of and at the end", that should be the only thing in the file, because one file equals one string (I know, that's not what my answer does).

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
egrep '\b(abc){2}\b' input
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this fits.

```
$ grep '\<abcabc\>'
test
abcabc
abcabc
test abcabc
test abcabc
testabcabc
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, from your answers, i think i have got what i need.

As i said in my questions, i want to match "`abcabc`", where 2 and only repeated "`abc`", no other characters in front of and at the end of, but "`abcabc`" is not the only string in that line.

so the answers is:

```
grep -n "\b\\(abc\\)\\{2\\}\b" filename
```